# Using Perspective Rendering To Render A 3D Point

Tags: rendering, 3d, perspective, camera, render

I am wondering how I can use perspective rendering to render a point onto a screen. An image showing perspective rendering:

[image: Picture of perspective rendering]

Say I have a 3d point (with x, y, and z coordinates), a point for the camera, and a lookat point for the camera (the point that the camera is facing), how can I use this to plot the point?

In pseudo-code:

```
cameraPosition = [10, 6, 5] // Camera coordinates
cameraLookat = [5, 6, 5] // Where the camera is looking
pointA = [5, 5, 5] // X, Y, and Z coordinates

// Perspective render it to get 2d-coordinates
pointA2D = perspectivePlot(pointA, cameraPosition, cameraLookat)
```

How would the `perspectivePlot` function work? From my understanding, it needs to plot a line between the `cameraPosition` and `pointA`, then find where the line intersects a plane that is 1 unit away from `cameraPosition` at the angle determined by `cameraLookat`.

How would this be done?

Comment: Are you saying you need help computing the intersection of a line and a plane?

Comment: You can either find the ray-plane intersection or you can transform the point and plane to the camera's coordinate system (the plane corresponding to $z=1$) and then divide by $z$: $(x,y,z) \rightarrow (x/z, y/z)$